# Error when using questionmark in ANTLR4 actions

Tags: c#, antlr4

I'm testing ANTLR 4 with C# as target language.

The Definitive ANTLR 4 reference says:

> Actions are arbitrary chunks of code written in the target language
> (the language in which ANTLR generates code) enclosed in {...}. We can
> do whatever we want in these actions as long as they are valid target
> language statements

However, I get an error if I place a '?' inside {...}

This works:

```
    | ID '(' exprList? ')'      { $result = creator.CreateFunctionCall( $ID, null, $exprList.result ); }
```

But if I add a questionmark, to take care of the optional exprList, ANTLR, not C#, gives an error:

```
    | ID '(' exprList? ')'      { $result = creator.CreateFunctionCall( $ID, null, $exprList?.result ); }
```

> Error ANT02   error(67): Expr.g4:4:156: missing attribute access on rule
> reference exprList in $exprList

Is this an error in ANTLR? Or can you use an escape code or similar?

Comment: The problem is that Antlr defines a [parser rule attribute](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/actions.md#parser-rule-attributes) of the form `<id> '.' <id>`. Antlr does not allow anything else. When you add the '?', attribute reference is no longer recognized. The workaround is to write your action in "target agnostic format"--which you should always do anyways.

Comment: It looks like the generated code tests for null references. So if `exprList?` is empty, the value of attribute `$exprList.result` is null, and you shouldn't then get null pointer dereference.

Comment: Hi Kaby, Thanks for clarifying. I get a null pointer exception in the generated code. '_exprList' is null in '_localctx._exprList.result'. As a workaround I currently have two rules, one with no parameters and one with a list.

Comment: @MadsN oh, after posting an answer, I saw you comment. Yes, that is a fine workaround.

Comment: Antlr generates different code for built-in attribute "text". For "locals"-declared attributes, there is no null-ptr guard. E.g., an action containing `System.Console.WriteLine("yo " + $expression.text + $expression.result);`, where `result` is a "locals" attribute, the tool generates `System.Console.WriteLine("yo " + $expression.text + $expression.result);`. That makes sense because the tool doesn't know when the attribute is a value or ref type. Best to refactor the grammar, or use "target agnostic format" actions.

Comment: @kaby76 It's ok, I just needed to know how it works. I ended up with doing an 'optExprList' instead of 'exprList'. The opt variant returns an empty list if no expression are given. That way I don't need to make two rules everytime I need a list.

Comment: @kaby76 Regarding a language agnostic refactoring. Speed is a concern to me, so I try to make choices thats keeps performance high. It seems it has not been a top priority when doing ANTLR, which seems to be more focused on patterns and design. ANTLR migth be the wrong choice, but it seems like the thing everybody is using as first choice these days so I wan't to try it out and see how it works out and perhaps switch it out with a handmade parser later if needed. Until then I want give ANTLR the best conditions to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
| ID '(' exprList ')' { $result = creator.CreateFunctionCall( $ID, null, $exprList.result ); } 
| ID '(' ')'          { $result = creator.CreateFunctionCall( $ID, null, null ); }
```